# How should I add a simple one line script to my startup?

Tags: boot, command-line, startup, systemd

When I open the ubuntu terminal, I want it to run this code automatically:

`linuxlogo`

I have the linuxlogo package installed and I just installed systemd, but I haven't been able to figure out how to turn that one line into a script and insert it last in the boot process. It's not a big thing, but I would like to be able to do this.

Comment: If you want it to run when you open a terminal, just add it to the end of your `~/.bashrc` file (on a new line). Getting it to show up when the computer boots up is more complicated

Comment: Why did you have to install systemd?

Comment: @mikewhatever I missed that, but if they had to install systemd, and they don't know how to do something when they open a terminal, something very strange is happening with what they are doing. OP: Please don't just run commands without knowing what they do.

Answer (score 1):

Include the command in the `.bashrc`  file located in your home directory. That file is executed automatically each time you open an interactive terminal.

`.bashrc` is a hidden file in your home directory. You will be able to see it in your file manager if you turn "Show hidden files"  on.